# How to make an executable jar in net beans (JDK 7)?

Tags: netbeans, jar, build, executable, netbeans-8

I have a project which i need to be made as an executable jar file. I used clean and build option in project, right-click menu and it built normally. The problem is, I cant run the executable jar file in project's dist folder (giving an error saying it could not find the main class, but believe me, I have given the main class correctly). I tried this using an example project (Just a Jframe) and gave me the same error. It can be solved by lowering the JDK version into **JDK 6** (current version is **JDK 7**)but for that i have to do major changes in my actual project (such as replacing all switches into for loops and replacing all multi catches in to single catches...etc). is there any way to make executable jar without changing JDK version?

**My netbeans version is 8.0.2**

[image: could not find main class error]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a "private static void main" in you main class.

If you open (not run) the Jar file in the dist folder.

Open the MANIFEST.MF file in /META-INF folder.

Do you see something like `Main-Class: com.satra.satra_finacials.view.main.MainFrame` ?

If not you can define your main class in `Menu File -> Project Properties (Satra_Financials) -> Category Run -> Main Class TextField`

Comment: I have opened the MANIFEST.MF and found that the main class is defined as you mentioned above. And my main class is public static. But the issue is every other projects (including this one I suppose) work perfectly when build using JDK 6. I don't know what the issue with JDK 7. Someone told me that netbeans 8.0 could be the problem. then I built with netbeans 7.2 and 7.4 and met with the same issue. Anyway, appreciate your answer :)

Comment: I use Netbeans with Java 5, 6, 7 and 8 and without any problem.
Could it be that you have some kind of problem with your JDK installation?